# Breakpoint at end of if statement in VS Code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

How can I place a breakpoint at the end of an if statement when debugging C++ code using CMake Tools and the C/C++ extension?

Here is some sample code:

```
int a = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i < a) {
    b += i;
  } // <-- I would like to break here and check the value of b, so I place breakpoint here
}
otherCode(b); // <-- this is where the debugger breaks
```

Now I will do a hack like `int HACK_REMOVE = 0;` at the end of the if statement, but it is annoying to have to do that. Is there another way to break at the end of a statement?

Comment: that line of text has no code, so no address to break at, your hack is the only way to break at the end of the block, you could create a `#define BREAK int HACK=0` and create a empty version for non-debug build. Use it with `BREAK;`

Comment: Since breakpoints work by replacing an instruction, it is unlikely to be possible without your hack.

Comment: Use a conditional breakpoint on if-line when !(i < a).

Comment: Can't you break at the closing brace? In any case, you could have a breakpoint on `b += i;` and then step once to see what happens to `b`. That might be even better, as you will have a before-and-after view.